# multiple select with optgroups IOS fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

Have come across a situation where I need to use multiple selects with grouping on my site.  There is a huge problem with IOS when trying to use this functionality.  I did some research and apparently this bug has been around for quite some time.  Has anyone found a solution in the meantime?  I am up to try anything... fixes, workarounds, completely different method of offering multiple select, etc... I just need to give users the ability to select multiples from groups (my only requirement).

My testing involves an iphone with 7.0.6 (latest at the time of writing).  From what I could find this happened back with 6.0 as well?  Being such a basic and 'old' functionality of html this is borderline insane that Apple has not fixed this problem.

**html :**

Using as this way mobile safari literally crashes.

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="settings[users]">
    <optgroup label="Computer 1">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Computer 2">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Using this way it will not crash, however, the issue with selected items is apparent.  If I select the first 5 options then as soon as I click 'done' it changes to 4.  If I do not select anything then the first disabled option 'Computer 1' is selected which should be impossible.  I believe that is due to the js fix listed below though.

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="settings[users]">
    <option disabled="disabled">Computer 1</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">Computer 2</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

**Possible JS fix I found :**

This fix appears to not handle optgroups (which I must have as different computers may have the same options, but would be a different value altogether), but even then does not solve the issues.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
    $('select[multiple]').each(function(){
        var select = $(this).on({
            "focusout": function(){
                var values = select.val() || [];
                setTimeout(function(){
                    select.val(values.length ? values : ['']).change();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        var firstOption = '<option value="" disabled="disabled"';
        firstOption += (select.val() || []).length > 0 ? '' : ' selected="selected"';
        firstOption += '>&laquo; Select ' + (select.attr('title') || 'Options') + ' &raquo;';
        firstOption += '</option>';
        select.prepend(firstOption);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Safari still crashes with `optgroup`s in iOS 9. Madness.

Comment: I ended up using a jquery script to display options (select2) which this problem no longer applied in that case due to the way the script functions and how it displays.  I am not sure if the original problem still happens or not as I have not checked.  I did try to submit a bug report to Apple, but kept getting the automated emails 'is this still a problem? please provide more information' which tells me nobody physically looked at it - I gave everything they needed to reproduce it just like I did here - should have been easy for them to check.

Comment: Ok thanks for getting back to me. A lost cause it seems.